# How to modify qtwebbrowser defaults?

Tags: html, qt

While playing with qtqwebbrowser

https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-apps/qtwebbrowser.git

the two questions arise:

1.) How can I set an initial URL when opening the browser ?
2.) How can I disable the virtual keyboard when using desktop platforms ?

Comment: Regarding 1.) I realized that the app's initlalURL argument must not contain "-" (in contradiction to the other app args) so just the plain URL, however, the site is still not loaded. If anyone can confirm please let me know.

Comment: After getting familiar with QML I realized that Browserwindow.qml contained a bug:
navigation.load();
had to be changed to
navigation.load(url);
So this one is resolved – now I check how to disable the virtual keyboard for desktop platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qtwebbrwoser is an example application in beta state which contains issues related to both questions:

1.) The app's initlalURL argument must not contain "-" (in contradiction to the other app args) so just the plain URL. Then in Browserwindow.qml navigation.load(); has to be changed to navigation.load(url)

2.) Disabling the virtual keyboard is not supported by default. However, it can be achieved by introducing the visibility property in the respective QML file (Main.qml) and set it from the C++ end via e.g. object->setProperty("keyboardVisible", false);